# Error: Parse Error: Line 72: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm currently using reactjs with formsy-react.
I want to do server-rendering so I'm using node.js.
To use Formsy I need to do:

```
var Formsy = require('formsy-react');

<Formsy.Form url="#" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} id="submit-job-form" >
    My form...
</Formsy.Form>
```

The problem is that node.js doesn't like it as it failed:
Error: Parse Error: Line 72: Unexpected token .

What can I do to make it work? On client side it works perfectly.

I try with

```
node --harmony server.js
```

but it doesn't change anything

Thank you

Edit: 
My package.json

```
Here is my package.json:

{
  "name": "My project",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build-dev": "browserify js/App.js -o bundle.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.0.0",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.0.0",
    "ejs": "~0.8.5",
    "express": "~4.0.0",
    "path": "*",
    "react": "~0.13.2",
    "react-router": ">=0.13.2",
    "react-interpolate-component": ">0.6.2",
    "react-select": ">0.4.0",
    "react-translate-component": ">=0.8.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "=0.21.1",
    "react-intl": "=1.2.0",
    "formsy-react":"0.13.1",
    "moment": "2.9.0",
    "toastr": "2.0.4",
    "counterpart": ">=0.16.4",
    "intl": "~0.1.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "browserify": "~3.20.0",
    "gulp": "~3.8.9",
    "gulp-browserify": "~0.5.1",
    "gulp-concat": "~2.4.1",
    "node-jsx": "~0.2.0",
    "react-tools": "^0.12.0",
    "reactify": "0.15.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: You have to convert JSX to JavaScript first.

Comment: Without knowing what line 72 is, it will be very difficult to help you. 
Please post your code on jsfiddle or paste your code while making clear the line numbers.

Comment: I would love to help, but could you post he line numbers first please?

Comment: Line 72 is the one with <Formsy.Form .

Comment: You should compile it to JS first https://facebook.github.io/react/jsx-compiler.html

Comment: Are you using any bundler (E.g. browserify)?

Comment: I added my package.json. Thanks for your help

Comment: compile your jsx code to js.

Answer (score 0):

node.js is thinking your code is JavaScript (which it's not). That why you're getting a `Parse Error` (meaning it can't parse it). You need to compile first. One tool you can use, as pointed out in the comments, is [JSX Compiler Service](https://facebook.github.io/react/jsx-compiler.html).

Comment: Thanks. But what is "node-jsx": "~0.2.0", for then? How can I automate the task? with Gulp?

Comment: The thing is that all my other JSX code is working. It is just this component with this name "Formsy.Form" that fails...